# AngularJS fire change event when model updated programmatically

Tags: angularjs, watch, angularjs-ng-change

The fact that ng-change is only for user input, and does not fire when changes are made to the model programmatically, is really causing me a headache today. I'm working with a user input form which has the separate parts of a name, as well as dynamically built and ordered credentials. The form has a "displayName" field that gets updated when the name parts are changed. This is encapsulated in a directive which I need to use in a larger view. Here's where things get hairy. I need to hide the name part fields in my directive and use the outer form's name fields. I thought this would be easy by wiring up a function to update the hidden text input fields, and thus my displayName field. Then I found out programmatic changes to the model do not fire the change event.

I tried creating a watch for one of the name fields to see if I could get it to update the displayName field, but no luck.

```
this.scope.$watch('provider.firstName', function (event) {
            namePropertyChanged2(displayNameOverridden, displayName, provider, credentials);
        });
```

When I change the input field for firstName, it modifies the directive's value 'provider.firstName', and runs the 'namePropertyChanged2' function. The code listed runs in an initialize function, where 'displayName' is a local variable assigned from this.scope.provider.displayName. The watch assignment required me to make local variables instead of passing in controller variables. Not sure why, but whatever. So this function runs and 'displayName' is updated with the correct value... and the input field it's bound to is not updated. Bummer.

What would be ideal is to manually trigger the change event when the model changes, which would update the displayName and much rejoicing to be had.

Comment: It's very hard to understand your description without seeing any code. But I have the feeling that all you need is `Display name: {{ getDisplayName() }}`, and a `getDisplayName()` function on the $scope that assembles all the parts of the display name together and returns it.

Comment: Make sure that the value you want to watch is present on the scope. Try `scope.$eval('provider.firstName')`. Alternatively, you can just pass a function to `$watch` to eval in each digest loop.

Comment: Please show the code of the directive that is not working and an example of how it is used.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix this, but I worked around it. If anyone has insight on how to manually trigger the change event on an input field, I'm still interested in the answer. I know that ng-change is only for user input, but my question would be why that is, and how to make the change event trigger even when the model is changed programmatically.